# Run a function in parallel and join its outputs

Tags: python

I built an experimental setup for my thesis in which I perform a certain experiment x times. I'll spare the details but it basically trains multiple models & evaluates its outputs within each experiment iteration.

The function's structure is:

```
def experiment(minority_class_proportions, repetitions, dataset, target_set_size, data_used):
        ....
        results = {
            'all_cv_boost': cv_boost,
            'all_cv_csboost': cv_csboost,
            'all_sra_boost': sra_boost,
            'all_sra_csboost': sra_csboost,
            'all_auc_boost': auc_boost,
            'all_auc_csboost': auc_csboost,
            'all_aec_boost': aec_boost,
            'all_aec_csboost': aec_csboost,
            'all_save_boost': save_boost,
            'all_save_csboost': save_csboost
        }
        
        return results
```

And I am currently trying to get it to work like this on a toy number of repetitions within each experiment (which should take a minute or 2). But it keeps on running so I think I'm doing something wrong. This should run the experiment 8 times if it does what I want it to do.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []
    with Pool(8) as p:
        results.append(p.starmap(experiment, [(minority_class_proportions, repetitions, dataset, target_set_size, data_used)]))
    p.join()
    print(results)
```

Is it possible to parallellize this?